# Lack of reproducibility during stream simulation

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink stream program that performs certain operations on a keyed, windowed stream.
The operators make use of the `KeyedStateStore` returned by `Context#globalState()`
(see [Flink docu](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction)).

In the actual real-time stream, I have no issues.
However, I have certain special scenarios where I need to simulate the stream,
for which I need to load a certain amount of data and order it by timestamp.
The operator I have to assign watermarks is implemented in a way that can handle both cases.

My problem is that, unless I execute the stream simulation with parallelism=1,
I don't have reproducible results.
I pressume that my source can emit events at a faster rate than my window process function,
and maybe several windows for a given key are queued in a way that doesn't necessarily preserve time order.
Since the window process function modifies state assuming time order,
there could be race conditions that leave state inconsistent.

In the simulated version, late arrivals aren't even allowed, so that shouldn't be a problem.
Parallelism=1 always yields the same results
(some unit tests check this).

Could anyone confirm if stream simulation is a supported use case for Flink?
And if it is, whether the aforementioned behavior would be a bug if confirmed?

---

### Update 1

Here's the high-level overview of the stream pipeline:

```
input = source with default parallelism (message bus could have multiple partitions)
keySelector = CustomKeySelector

timestampedStream = input
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WaterMarker)
    .setParallelism(1) // see Remark 1

streamFork1 = timestampedStream.flatMap(FlatMapFunction1)
streamFork2 = timestampedStream.flatMap(FlatMapFunction2)

streamFork1
    .keyBy(keySelector)
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindow)
    .process(ProcessWindowFunction1) // stateful (global)
    .addSink(MessageBusSink)

internalStream = streamFork2
    .keyBy(keySelector)
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindow)

internalStream
    .process(ProcessWindowFunction2) // stateful (window)
    .addSink(DatabaseSink1)
    .setParallelism(1)

internalStream
    .process(ProcessWindowFunction3) // stateful (global)
    .addSink(DatabaseSink2)
    .setParallelism(1)
```

*Remark 1*: The source is not under my control,
so I can't assign timestamps at the source.
That's why I need to assign watermarks with parallelism=1,
since some partitions in the stream could actually be empty
(at least for a while).

And my watermarker's logic
(class implements `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks`,
remarks below):

```
private final TemporalUnit slideTime;

private Instant maxEventTime = null;
private Instant maxEventTimeTruncated = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L);
private Instant lastWatermarkTimeTruncated = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L);
private long forceAdvanceMultiplier = 1L;

public TimestampExtractorAndPeriodicWatermarker(TemporalUnit slideTime) {
    this.slideTime = slideTime;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
    if (maxEventTime == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Instant truncatedInstant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(slideTime);

    if (Duration.between(maxEventTimeTruncated, maxEventTime).compareTo(slideTime.getDuration()) >= 0) {
        // generate watermark when the newest event time is >= max (truncated) event time + slide time
        lastWatermarkTimeTruncated = truncatedInstant;
        maxEventTimeTruncated = maxEventTime.truncatedTo(slideTime);
        return new Watermark(maxEventTime.toEpochMilli());

    } else if (truncatedInstant.compareTo(lastWatermarkTimeTruncated) > 0) {
        // generate watermark every "slide" time if no new events arrive
        lastWatermarkTimeTruncated = truncatedInstant;
        Instant timeToForceAdvanceFlinkTime = this.maxEventTime
                .truncatedTo(slideTime)
                .plus(slideTime.getDuration().multipliedBy(forceAdvanceMultiplier++));

        return new Watermark(timeToForceAdvanceFlinkTime.toEpochMilli());
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public long extractTimestamp(T t, long l) {
    long elemTS = t.getTimestamp();
    if (maxEventTime == null) {
        maxEventTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(elemTS);
    } else {
        maxEventTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.max(elemTS, maxEventTime.toEpochMilli()));
    }
    forceAdvanceMultiplier = 1L;
    return elemTS;
}
```

My system's throughput could be very low,
but I *need* windows to be closed even if no new data arrives every minute,
that's why I need the logic with `forceAdvanceMultiplier`.
I believe thread safety isn't an issue here,
but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, this should be workable -- one can achieve reproducible, deterministic results when processing historic or simulated data. But it's also fairly easy to do things that lead to non-determinism. Without more information, one can only speculate on the cause(s).

Non-determinism in Flink arises from one of two things: (1) writing a job that is sensitive to races between parallel pipelines, and from (2) the use of processing time rather than event time (which you might think of as races between the events and the system clock).

For any given key, there will be only one single-threaded instance of the window operator, and it will trigger its event time windows in order, as the watermarks ascend. If the results are inconsistent within a single key, then I suspect that either (1) the watermarking is incorrectly implemented, or depends in some way on the system clock rather than event time timestamps, or (2) the events for a single key come from multiple source instances, and your windowing computation is sensitive to races between these independent sources.

And even if the results are consistent within each key, if you are then combining these per-key results into some sort of global result, it would be easy enough to introduce some non-determinism in that final combining stage.

Update:

I believe your watermarking is going to produce some indeterminate number of late events, which then leads to irreproducible results. Let me explain.

The source is being read from in parallel, and if I've understood correctly, is sorted by timestamp. However, the parallelism is then reduced down to one for watermarking. At this point multiple (possibly) ordered streams are being interleaved together, resulting in a single out-of-order stream. Then the watermarking uses maxEventTime as the current watermark, without subtracting some delay from it to account for out-of-orderness, which then can cause out-of-order events to be late.

You can confirm this diagnosis by adding side outputs to the windows to surface any late events. The easiest fix would be to set the parallelism of the source to one.

Comment: (1) Watermarking does depend on the system clock for the real-time version, although it shouldn't affect the simulated version, how can system clock introduce problems? (2) I think there's only a sink after the window, but I'll have to check. What information would be useful to troubleshoot? I could post the high-level definition of the operators used in the stream.

Comment: For starters, I'd like to see the implementation of timestamp extractor and watermark assigner, and the high-level definition of the operators used in the stream.

Comment: I've updated the question. What you said about "parallel pipelines" could be an issue, I guess, but I'm not sure how Flink handles "forking" of a keyed, windowed stream.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about that. My source for simulation does have parallelism=1, but I actually transform it (`singleInput.map(...).filter(...)`) before assigning watermarks. The operators for those transformations have default parallelism, so they do split the stream (round-robin maybe), right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Each time the parallelism is changed that forces a rebalance, and when those split streams come back together the original ordering is lost.

Comment: I'll probably have to make sure things are working as expected, but my initial tests look promising. Thanks again.